# category of or of category

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

I came across a sentence in a reputed grammar book today that read like this -

> This category of students have not developed their reading skills.

I know that the sentence sounds right and I've followed a similar structure myself multiple times while talking to people but for some reason, I felt that there was something wrong with the way *category of* was used here. 
Since we are talking about the students here and not the category, shouldn't the sentence be -

> The students of this category have not developed their reading skills.

To give you a bit of perspective - the author had divided all the students in 4 categories, depending upon their reading skills, in the preceding paragraph and in this one, he was talking about the second category of students.

Comment: If you google **collective nouns** you will find that most authorities concur that the choice of singular or plural verbs depends on the context rather than any rule. But I disagree with the answer below which suggests the plural **have** with the singular **its**. It's either **have...their** or **has....its** although some might prefer **has...their** (with the singular their).

Comment: you should have written it as an answer. It did clarify things for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a choice between:

> this category of students have not developed their reading skills

and,

> the students of this category have not developed their reading skills

I would personally prefer the second choice. The first choice, whether grammatically correct or not, caused me to reread the contents to be sure that I fully understood what the writer meant. The second choice  did not possess this level of ambiguity, so I could more easily understand its meaning in one reading.

If I were to make any change at all, it would be to drop "the" before "students" and change the preposition from "of" to "in", e.g.:

> students in this category have not developed their reading skills

but that is getting down to matters of style rather than matters of substance.

Answer (score 0):

What about : 'this category of students have not developed *its* reading skills'?

I should not think 'category' should be considered a collective, but rather a neutral substantive, which tends indeeds to reify the individuals included in the 'category'but sounds grammatically correct to my ears.

Comment: Then it should be "has not", shouldn't it? Anyway, "(the) students in this category" is much better, polemic wise, isn't it?

Comment: The problem here is that students develop reading skills, but categories can't read.

Comment: since you are using the verb 'have' in your sentence, you are treating category as a plural, in which case, its is incorrect because it stands for a singular noun.

Comment: @user18593 — True. I focused on 'its' and missed that most elementary one.